# How do I get a specific snapkey from firebase data snapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database like this:

[image: My database image]

I am trying to check all the snapkeys so that I find one that matches with the one provided by user and access its child values. I am new to firebase db and the documentation was not clear on that.

This is what I tried but it does not work

```
  const db = getDatabase();
    const thumbnailRef = ref(db, "Contents/");

    onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const childData = childSnapshot.val();
        setTestProducts((prev) => [...prev, childData]);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand the question, but to access the key of each `childSnapshot`, you'd do:

```
const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
```

If you want to store both the keys and the value for all products, you can do something like:

```
onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const childData = childSnapshot.val();
    const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    setTestProducts((prev) => [...prev, { key: childKey, data: childData }]);
  });
})
```

Or preferably with a single call to the state setter:

```
onValue(thumbnailRef, (snapshot) => {
  let testProducts = []
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const childData = childSnapshot.val();
    const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    testProducts.push({ key: childKey, data: childData });
  });
  setTestProducts((testProducts);
})
```

Comment: I meant how do I fetch the keys only, by keys I mean the unique code created by firebase.

Comment: Did you try the `const childKey = childSnapshot.key;` that I showed in my first snippet? That should give you the key of each node. What happened when you did that? Was there an error?

Comment: this was helpful. It worked